# getting list of records in a subgrid using webapi or fetchxml

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to get list of all records that are in a subgrid in a form

Is there a way to get it using some api call or using javascript?
The below code will fetch the rows if the subgrid is available in the form but
I don't want to have the subgrid in the form where I am going to fetch these records

```
var selectedRows = Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getGrid().getSelectedRows();
var rows = Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getGrid().getRows();
```

For example, assume that I have a medicalCase entity form, where I am having patients subgrid. I want to get the list of records in the patients subgrid using webapi in some other entity form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve records using fetch.

1. Determine the fetchxml behind your view. Easiest way to do this is to pull up your view in Advanced Find and then use the Download Fetch Xml button.
2. Use a library like the xrmservicetoolkit to execute your fetch statement.

   ```
   var fetchXml =
           "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
              "<entity name='contact'>" +
                 "<attribute name='contactid' />" +
                 "<attribute name='firstname' />" +
                 "<attribute name='lastname' />" +
                 "<attribute name='accountrolecode' />" +
                 "<filter>" +
                    "<condition attribute='contactid' operator='eq' value='" + contactId + "' />" +
                 "</filter>" +
              "</entity>" +
           "</fetch>";

   var retrievedContacts = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(fetchXml);
   console.log(retrievedContacts[0].attributes['lastname'].value)
   ```

   See [this page](http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Soap%20Functions) for more info.

Comment: where can I specify the name of the subgrid? 
In the advanced find I am only able to select fields

Comment: In Adv Find, choose your entity, then in the Use Saved View box choose the same view that your sub-grid uses.